# How to use python csv module in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to instantiate a csv writer in the init method of a class and I want to use it from a class method storeToCSV(). For some strange reason this does not work. No data is written to the file when I call self.storeToCSV(['test']). What is the reason for this and how can I fix this?

```
class postprocessing:
    def __init__(self,topic):

        try:
           os.remove(topic+'.csv')
        except:
           pass

        csvfile = open(topic+'.csv', 'a')
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
        self.csvwriter.writerow(['id','url1'])

    def storeToCSV(self, arg_a):           
        print self.csvwriter.writerow(arg_a)
```

Comment: Can you add a few lines to make this a working demo of the problem? The code given should work fine so its likely a matter of how you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a

```
csvfile.close()
```

after writing the data.

Answer (score 0):

The code works here. Calling
`postprocessing('afile').storeToCSV(['1', 'c9.io'])`

Fills up afile.csv with

```
id;url1
1;c9.io
```

Make sure you don't read from the file before the writer object is deleted and the file object is closed as data isn't written immediately to disk.
And don't close the file before you're done writing to it.